# Unable to run "catkin_make"

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

#### Quick Glance:

I am using **ROS2 Humble** on **Ubuntu Jammy(22.04)** and i was trying to integrate **YDLidar** by following this [Guide](https://www.generationrobots.com/blog/en/lidar-integration-with-ros-quickstart-guide-and-projects-ideas/) and in point we have to Run `catkin_make` but i am unable to use it.

#### What i Did:

I tried to run `sudo apt install catkin` and i got this error: `E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
python3-catkin-pkg : Conflicts: catkin but 0.8.10-7 is to be installed
python3-catkin-pkg-modules : Conflicts: catkin but 0.8.10-7 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I went though this [ROS page](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/catkin/html/user_guide/installation.html) unable to fix by changing the last command based on my ROS version but i got this error

```
E: Package 'python-catkin-pkg' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'python-empy' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'python-nose' has no installation candidate
```

I tried [This](https://answers.ros.org/question/350517/ros2-install-catkin/) also, I too got same error.

So, please help me /
It will be really Great-full

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/412875/unable-to-run-%22catkin_make%22/) by [SukarnaJana](https://answers.ros.org/users/140757/sukarnajana/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no `catkin_make` in ROS 2.

The tutorial you link is from 2019, and was written for ROS Melodic, which is a ROS 1 version.

You'll have to either ask the author to update the tutorial (I don't expect that to happen), or find a tutorial which specifically supports ROS 2 Humble.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2023-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SukarnaJana](https://answers.ros.org/users/140757/sukarnajana/) on 2023-02-28**:
Thanks for bringing this point under my notice, that Catkin is not there in ROS2